# How to remove public from url in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want ro remove `public` word from the url in laravel. I tried updating `.htaccess` and renaming `server.php` to `index.php` file but after that I got path error. All the css, js, fonts are not working without public word in the url. Please help me so that I can set all the path of css, js, fonts and remove public word from url in laravel. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Move your all files from `/public` to your root folder `/` (which is mainly your laravel folder).

Now open `index.php` file and edit 2 lines, as below :

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
// changed to
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

&

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
// changed to
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Now add this lines to your `.htaccess` to prevent access `.env` from URL :

```
<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

By this method you can host your laravel app in any kind of shared hosting too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But other sources say we just have to rename server.php to index.php

Comment: @Lamar, `server.php` and `index.php` both are different  file

Comment: yes, but server.php is acutally including public/index.php, however when I do that the redirect doesn't wok

Comment: @Lamar You don't need to change `server.php`,  I installed a lot of laravel project on cPanel, I never edit `server.php`

Comment: The thing is I thought it would be easier just to rename server.php and not have to change the paths found in in /public/index.php or to change css and js files in app.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

add .htaccess file in the root of your laravel application.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

It will work fine, no need to changes the server.php file or anything else.

> (support laravel version > 5.0*)