# Remove /public after https redirect laravel .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have a Laravel Page Deployed in a Shared Hosting and when I force http request to redirect to https the url contains /public

My root .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

And my /public .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Remove /public/ from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Header always set Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

The only problem here is: when you type the url like example.com it will redirect to https://example.com/public and everything works just fine. Even if you type https://example.com it works and dont append /public to the url.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove public from url in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62128581/how-to-remove-public-from-url-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in root .htaccess

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
 
    <ifmodule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </ifmodule>
     
    RewriteEngine On
     
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 
 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php
 
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your answer and described what you changed and why you changed it, why does it work?