# how to remove 'public' in url when redirecting http:// to https:// in laravel using htaccess?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, url-rewriting, laravel-8, http-redirect

when I open website using `https://example.com` it will open without `public` in the URL, but when I try to open `http://example.com` it will redirect to `https://example.com/public`, with `public` in the URL.

I want to redirect `http://` to `https://` but without `public` in the URL.

**Folder Structure:**

[image: Folder structure]

**.htaccess file code which is in root directory**

```
#disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

#PROTECT ENV FILE
<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

#PROTECT ENV FILE
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit -1
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit -1
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

**.htaccess file code which is in public directory**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: please help me to find out, where i went wrong!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove /public after https redirect laravel .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475931/remove-public-after-https-redirect-laravel-htaccess)

Comment: There is no HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the code you posted. Do you know where this is being triggered? (Do you have access to the server config?) What is the 3xx HTTP status code used in the redirect? "...it will redirect to `https://example.com/public`" - do you mean `/public/` (with a trailing slash)? Or is there literally no trailing slash after the redirect (this is significant)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the code you posted. If this is being performed earlier in the server config then it will need to be corrected in the server config. However, if it is being performed (incorrectly) later in your application then you can correct this by redirecting early in `.htaccess`. This will need to go at the top of your `/public/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(This does assume the SSL cert is installed directly on your application server and you are not using a proxy to manage your SSL connection. If so, then the *condition* will need to be adjusted.)

Since this is in the `/public/.htaccess` file, the captured backreference `$1` will naturally exclude the `/public/` subdirectory, so this is excluded from the redirect.

You should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. And make sure you've cleared your browser cache before testing.

However, the following rule is problematic and will also expose the `/public` subdirectory should you request a URL with a trailing slash:

> ```
> # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
> RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
> ```

This rule would be OK if it was in the root `.htaccess` file, however, with it being in the `/public/.htaccess` file (which it needs to be) then the `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the `/public/` directory (after the request is internally rewritten). And you are capturing the URL-path from the variable.

This rule should be written like this instead:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is also marginally more efficient and works regardless of which `.htaccess` file it is placed in (although it should be in the `/public/.htaccess` file, not the root `.htaccess`). *Aside:* If the `/public` subdirectory was not *hidden* from the URL then this would not work, but that is not the case here.